# How can I convert combined literal constant into wchar in compile time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a combined literal constant defined in preprocessor macros such as

```
#define A "1"
#define B "3"
#define VERSION A "." B
```

Eventually I would like to convert it later to wchar_t * by using _T macro such as:

```
TCHAR * version = _T(VERSION);
```

However it fails to compile with Visual Studio 2013 runtime with the following error:

> concatenating mismatched strings

It seems that it's fixed in newer versions and above code gets compiled with no problems using VS2015 runtime.

Any ideas how to make it work with VS2013 runtime?

Comment: If it works in 2015, why don't you upgrade? The Community version is free. Each version *does* improve the compiler. Later fixes won't work on previous versions

Comment: Check the [C++ String Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t(v=vs.120).aspx) page on the correct way to specify wide string literals, ie use the `L` prefix. If you use `wchar_t` explicitly, there is no reason to use `_T`

Answer (score 2):

They all need to be wide or narrow, try:

```
#define A L"1"
#define B L"3"
#define VERSION A L"." B

const wchar_t * version = VERSION;
```

Or

```
#define A "1"
#define B "3"
#define VERSION A "." B

const char * version = VERSION;
```

Edit: this one answers the comment

```
#define A "1"
#define B "3"
#define VERSION A "." B

#define EXPAND(x) _T(##x)
#define TO_WIDE(x) (EXPAND(x))

const wchar_t * version = TO_WIDE(VERSION);
```

Comment: Let's say I have those defines in another header file that I cannot modify. And I need to use the value as wchar_t.

Comment: #define WIDE_VERSION _T(A) L"." _T(B)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like the best solution for now. However I'd like to find out if there's any more generic solution for this problem.

Comment: Apart from using macros to redefine the header or convert the string from narrow to wide at run time there isn't much you can do: edit: found a way via the token pasting, edit: nevermind that just returns "Version" instead of the real string :(

Comment: It seems like it still generates compilation error for VS2013 runtime.

Comment: This snippet works in MSVC2013 update 3 for me and prints "1.3" via std::wcout ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116106/discussion-between-michauzo-and-paulm).

Comment: @michauzo `L` is the way to specify Unicode literals. It's available since Visual C++ 6 at least. Your code tried to convert ASCII to Unicode using `_T()` for the wrong reason.

Comment: Okay, I should use TCHAR * instead. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't find a perfect solution. But I found how to modify creation of VERSION macro to be able to simply apply _T macro to it. The code is following:

```
#define MAJOR 3
#define MINOR 1

#define DOT .

#define __STR2(x) #x
#define __STR(x) __STR2(x)

#define _CONCAT3(s1, s2, s3) s1 ## s2 ## s3
#define CONCAT3(s1, s2, s3) _CONCAT3(s1, s2, s3)

#define VERSION_STR __STR(CONCAT3(MAJOR, DOT, MINOR))
```

and then

```
TCHAR * version = _T(VERSION);
```

works fine.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to 2015 instead? The Community edition is free. *Why* keep supporting bugs that are already fixed?

Comment: First, you are trying to *backport* code. It *is* that simple in this case - use the proper compiler version instead of trying to hack it. As others pointed out, it even works in 2013 with the proper update. Second, you are trying to use macros instead of the wstring type, and even use the wrong literal (ie you miss the `L`). Not a good idea in general.